# Missing @JsonTypeInfo property in serialized list with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jackson-databind

Jackson 2.9.2 allows to specify a property on a superclass to distinguish the type of subclasses with `JsonTypeInfo`, e.g.

```
@XmlRootElement
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS,
              include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
              property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = MyEntity.class)})
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id",
    scope=MySuperEntity.class)
public class MySuperEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String myProperty;

    [0-arg constructor, (Long, String) contructor and getters and setters for both properties]
}
```

A class `MyEntity` with extends `MySuperEntity` and adds on `String` property with getter and setter can be serialized with

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
long myEntityId = 1l;
//test single
MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity(0,
        myEntityId,
        "");
String expResultSingle = String.format("{\n" +
        "  \"type\" : \"richtercloud.jackson.type.in.list.MyEntity\",\n" +
        "  \"id\" : %d,\n" +
        "  \"myProperty\" : \"\",\n" +
        "  \"someProperty\" : 0\n" +
        "}",
        myEntityId);
String result = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(myEntity);
assertEquals(expResultSingle,
        result);
```

However when put into a `LinkedList` the generated JSON output doesn't have the `type` property:

```
//test list
String expResultList = String.format("[ %s ]",
        expResultSingle);
result = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(myEntity)));
assertEquals(expResultList,
        result);
```

fails due to

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[ {
  "[type" : "richtercloud.jackson.type.in.list.MyEntity",
  "]id" : 1,
  "myProper...> but was:<[ {
  "[]id" : 1,
  "myProper...>
```

An SSCCE can be found at https://gitlab.com/krichter/jackson-type-in-list with test output illustrating the issue at https://gitlab.com/krichter/jackson-type-in-list/-/jobs/55921526.

Comment: I think that the observed behaviour is described in https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1308 and https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/pull/1309 and the answer to is "cleanest" answer is to use subclassing to remove genericness: `public class MyEntityList extends ArrayList<MyEntity> { }`

Comment: @helt: That should have been an answer. Personally, I think `mapper.writerFor(new TypeReference<>() {}).writeValue` is also pretty nice, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for `mapper.convertValue`, so in my case, I rolled with just `mapper.convertValue(new ArrayList<>(data) {})` (mind the `{}`),